# How to set a wallpaper using a viewpager

Tags: set, wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I am using a viewpager and loading images from url. I would like to implement a button to set the viewpager image as a phones wallpaper. Please help me as i am a rookie.

```
public class ImageDetails extends Activity {

    private ViewPager pager;

    private DisplayImageOptions options;
     protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_pager);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        Button buttonSetWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.downloads);
        ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        imagePreview.setImageResource();

        buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.wallpaper);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });




        //getting serialized data from MainActivity
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final List<String> imageUrls = bundle.getStringArrayList(ImageExtractor.IMAGES);
        final List<String> downloads = bundle.getStringArrayList(ImageExtractor.DOWNLOADS);
        final List<String> favs = bundle.getStringArrayList(ImageExtractor.FAV);

        int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(ImageExtractor.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

        //Setting DisplayImageOptions for UIL
          options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.stub_image) //setting image to show on loading
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build(); 

        //initializing viewpager  
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls,downloads,favs));
        pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);

    }







    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    //Adapter for Pager
    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private List<String> images;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<String> downloads;
        private List<String> favs;

        ImagePagerAdapter(List<String> images,List<String> d,List<String> f) {
            this.images = images;
            this.downloads=d;
            this.favs=f;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ImageDetails.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, final int position) {
            final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
        final TouchImageView imageView = (TouchImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);
             TextView down = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.downloads);
             TextView fav = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.Fav);

            down.setText(downloads.get(position) + " downloads");
            fav.setText(favs.get(position) + " liked");



            //displaying image using UIL
            imageLoader.displayImage(images.get(position), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason.getType()) {
                case IO_ERROR:
                message = "Input/Output error";
                break;
                case DECODING_ERROR:
                message = "Image can't be decoded";
                break;
                case NETWORK_DENIED:
                message = "Downloads are denied";
                break;
                case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                message = "Out Of Memory error";
                break;
                case UNKNOWN:
                message = "Unknown error";
                break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(ImageDetails.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                });
            view.addView(imageLayout, 0);
                return imageLayout;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }


        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```